# How to support Markdown links syntax "[text](link)" inside superscript syntex "^(text)"?

Tags: javascript, regex, markdown, markdown-it

So I'm using [Markdown-it](https://github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it) as my Markdown renderer, and I added some custom tags using [markdownitRegexp](https://github.com/iMrDJAi/markdown-it-regexp).

I have a problem with the superscript syntax `^(text)`, it ends with a ")" so you can't use links `[text](link)` because they ends with it too.

I wanna make it able to handle multiple links without any problem:

```
^(foo doo [bar](https://stackoverflow.com "baz") foo [doo](https://github.com)...)
```

That's what I'm using for now:

```js
window.markdownitRegexp(
    /\^\(([\s\S]+?)[\)]/,
    function (match, utils) {
        const html = inlineRenderer('supsubscript').render(match[1], env);
        return `<sup>${html.replace(/\<p\>|\<\/p\>\s/g, '')}</sup>`;
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with this one:

```
\^\(((?:\[[^\]]*\]\([^)]*\)|[\s\S])+?)\)
```